# Posting data on a confirmation page back to controller

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have the following cshtml here that has a model. This page is basically a confirmation page where the user gets to verify that all the information keyed in is correct before proceeding.

I have a link button (not shown in the code below) that will perform an ajax call back to my controller and persist all the data in `@Model` to my database

What I'm doing now is manually re-creating the json object by looping through the rows in the HTML table and extracting all the relevant data which I'll post back to my controller using $.post

Is there a more efficient/elegant way to do this?

What's the best practice in this case where I have a confirmation page showing non editable data before persisting it to my database

```
@model RegistrationViewModels.VerificationViewModel

<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <colgroup>
            <col class="col-xs-5">
            <col class="col-xs-1">
        </colgroup>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="active">
                <td colspan="2">Rooms</td>
            </tr>
            @foreach (var room in Model.Rooms)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @room.RoomType
                    </td>
                    <td>@String.Format("{0:C}", room.Price)</td>
                </tr>
            }
            <tr class="active">
                <td colspan="2">Particulars</td>
            </tr>
            @foreach (var occupant in Model.Occupants)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @occupant.FirstName
                    </td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            }

        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: save the model in session and retrieve after confirmation just like Chris Pratt said in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is pass the data on POST to a Get action, then accept POST on that actions:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Reservation _data)
{
  //do validation ...

  //now send the data to Confirm action to show the view that user can confirm. Pass the data along.
  return RedirectToAction("Confirm", "[Controller]", new {@_data = _data});
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Confirm(Reservation _data)
{
  return View(_data) //no need to use a different model in your verification page. Just don't make the Html fields editable. 
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Confirm(Reservation _data)
{
  //save 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not a fan of session use, in general, this is actually a situation where that's probably the best approach. Save the posted data to the session, show the page with that data. Then once the user confirms, you can read the data out of the session (rather than having to post it all over again), and save it to the database.